# jQuery Mobile (1.4) WebApp with Zurb Foundation - Custom Download Builder Choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I'm currently working on a simple mobile WebApp using [Zurb Foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and I only want to use the absolute minimum of [jQuery Mobile 1.4](http://jquerymobile.com/) to enable a multi-page main page (index + 4 small pages) paired with some multi-html additional pages.

I got my tech demo running with the full 1.4 version of jQuery Mobile (after stipping the CSS down to 28kb) but the jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js file is way to big with 188kb of mostly not used functions.

This is what I need:

1. Multi Page Functionality (multiple divs with data-role="page" in one html file)

   - automatic transformation of links without rel="external"
2. Multi HTML AJAX functionality (to insert additional pages via AJAX from separate files)
3. Dialog for Result Pages and additional information
4. History Functionality

   - Back Button
   - hashChange stuff

Using the [Download Builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) I tried to narrow it down but I'm not sure which modules I need and if I have to write additional js to make things work. I'll build the whole css myself (using foundation and my own stuff along with small jQuery Mobile CSS snippets) but I need the js magic from jQuery mobile with as little traffic payload as possible.

- Events

  - Navigate
- Navigation

  - Content Management
  - the rest gets selected anyway if I choose "Content Management"
- Widgets

  - Dialogs (for some mystical reason this is twice in the widgets section)

a) Anything else I forgot?
b) Do I have to add/write some custom stuff to make it work or is it all included in the jQuery Magic Download? There is an Init Core Module...

Comment: you will need _Core_, _Events_, _Navigation_ and _Transition (choose which transitions you want). Once you check _Init_, all options in the aforementioned sections will be selected. _Init_ will auto-initialize the whole framework on start-up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Guess, my fault was not to check Init. I got everything working so far. I'll play with it some more and maybe write a more elaborate answer about the individual modules myself for other people working with jQuery Mobile Modules.