# jQuery Mobile Page Page Transitions

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, transition

I used jQuery Mobile Builder to download a build for just transitions. But I can't get it to work with this build. The only way I've gotten it to work is to use the entire jQuery Mobile framework, but then it messes up the rest of my pages because it wasn't meant to use all of the other jQuery Mobile features.

I included my files in the like so:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='javascript/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='javascript/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.structure.css' />

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.mobile.custom.js"></script>
```

Then I want it to transition to the next page when this link is clicked/tapped:

```
<a class="create-hud-but" data-transition="pop" href="create2.html">
```

Like I said, this all works if I include full jQuery Mobile. Is there an easy way to just cut out the part for page transitions? Or am I maybe including the wrong version of jQuery for the custom build? I haven't even been able to find out which version of jQuery Mobile goes with which version of jQuery (although I've seen people mentioning the version have to match up).

Comment: jQM transitions are based on Ajax Navigation. They won't work without Ajax. jQM loads pages into DOM via Ajax not HTTP and then navigates between them. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/21703541/1771795

Comment: Isn't the proper code for making the AJAX call already built into jQM?

Comment: it depends on which options you have choosen? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782225/jquery-mobile-1-4-webapp-with-zurb-foundation-custom-download-builder-choice#comment32957054_21782225

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know what happens. Btw, do you know how to tell which jQM goes with which jQuery Version. Will the newest version of jQuery work with 1.4.1 jQM?

Comment: You need at least jquery 1.9 to work with 1.4.

Comment: Alright. Was using higher then that, so I don't think that was the problem. The reason I asked is I saw another thread where someone was using too high of a jQuery version before and lower it fix a jQM problem.

Comment: Alright. Got a new 1.4.0 build and made sure to get every last thing mentioned from Core, Events, ect and it's working now. The style files are still messing some stuff up, but I can fix that easily enough. Thanks for the help.